# How can I update a table from schema 'A' by the trigger from schema 'B'?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, apex, ora-00942

How can I update a table from schema 'A' by the trigger from schema 'B' which generates, when some updates have done in in a table from schema 'B', In ORACLE APEX.It shows the error "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist".
I have called both table like -

schema name.table name,
"schema name.table name",
table name,
"table name"

every possibility shows same error..("ORA-00942: table or view does not exist")

Comment: Yes, that is possible. But you need according privileges on the second table.

Comment: `schema.table` is correct but you also need permission from the owner.